# Twitter sdk in ios 5 regarding email address

Tags: iphone, ios, twitter, twitter-oauth

I have used Twitter sdk in ios 5.

I want to get the user email address, after authentication.

How to do this,

Comment: I have used oauth , but did not know how to get email id?

Answer (score 4):

The Twitter API does not supply the users e-mail address.

Comment: then ? i want to store user's detail.

Comment: Have you read the [Twitter API documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api)? All you want to know is in there. You can get the profile by calling: [GET users/show](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/users/show)